# What happens if you go to a GET style url with a POST request?

Tags: php, post, get

Let's say I have a page called `display.php` and the user is viewing `display.php?page=3`. I want to allow the user to do an action like voting via a POST request and then bring them back to the page they were on. So, If I do a POST request to `display.php?page=3` would the page information also be available to the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is 'yes'. You can use a GET-style URL as the submission URL for a POST form. PHP will have both the POST and GET information available to it in the usual ways when the form is submitted.

This is not to say that you *should* do this, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you can get request variables from the special global arrays:

```
$_GET['page'] (for GET requests)
$_POST['page'] (for POST requests)
$_REQUEST['page'] (for either)
```

It sounds like you are looking for "Redirect after Post", I would suggest separating display.php and vote.php into separate files. Vote looks something like this:

```
<?php
//vote.php
$page_number = (int)$_REQUEST['page'];
vote_for_page($page_number); //your voting logic
header('Location: display.php?page=' . $page_number); //return to display.php
```

Note that blindly accepting unsanitized form data can be hazardous to your app.

Edit: Some folks consider it bad form to use $_REQUEST to handle both cases. The hazard is that you may want to signal an error if you receive a GET when you expect a POST. Typically GET is reserved for viewing and POST is reserved for making changes (create/update/delete operations). Whether this is really a problem depends on your application.

Comment: I was thinking about the second option but I'd still like to know if the GET array will be populated despite making a POST request.

Comment: Anything making changes really should have a CSRF-prevention token as a parameter, so you really don't have to worry too much about someone using a GET (e.g., by getting someone to click a link) to do something nefarious.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the GET array is always filled with the URL parameters regardless of the request method. You can try it with a simple page like this:

```
<form action="test.php?a=b" method="post">
    <input name="a"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<pre>
POST:
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
GET:
<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
</pre>
```